# Stopping a service and waiting in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, service

How can I stop a service and wait for it to finish stopping in vbscript?

I've got this so far:

```
For Each objService in colServiceList
    If objService.DisplayName = "<my display name>" Then
        objService.StopService()
    End If
Next
```

Googling turned up a suggestion of using `objService.WaitForStatus( ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped )`, but running that gives me an error of "Object required: 'ServiceControllerStatus'".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WaitForStatus method isn't included in the WMI Win32_Service interface. I think that's from a .NET class. There's no equivalent WMI method.

You have to requery the WMI service object in order to get an updated status. Then you can exit a loop once the status changes to "Stopped".

```
Option Explicit

Const MAX_ITER = 30, _
    VERBOSE = True

Dim wmi, is_running, iter
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:")

For iter = 0 To MAX_ITER
    StopService "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS", is_running
    If Not is_running Then
        Log "Success"
        WScript.Quit 0
    End If

    WScript.Sleep 500
Next

Log "max iterations exceeded; timeout"
WScript.Quit 1

' stop service by name. returns false in is_running if the service is not
' currently running or was not found.
Sub StopService(svc_name, ByRef is_running)
    Dim qsvc, svc

    is_running = False
    Set qsvc = wmi.ExecQuery( _
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service " & _
        "WHERE Name = '" & svc_name & "'")
    For Each svc In qsvc
        If svc.Started Then
            is_running = True
            If svc.State = "Running" Then svc.StopService
            Log svc.Name & ": " & svc.Status
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub Log(txt)
    If VERBOSE Then WScript.StdErr.WriteLine txt
End Sub
```